# ASCX Page not recognizing variables from code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have the following code in a .ascx file for a website that I am working on:

```
        <% if (intfee3 > 0)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>Late Fee</td>
            <td><%=String.Format("{0:C}", intfee3)%></td>
        </tr>    
        <% }%>
```

Essentially, this block is checking if the variable intfee3 (created and initialized in the code behind file for this page) has a value greater than 0, and if it does, creates a new table row, and populates the row, formatting intfee3 for currency.

intfee3 is handled in the code behind as such:

```
public partial class LateFee : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected int intfee3;

        //A bunch of code here that handles other elements on page and is working

        //Check if there is a late fee
            if (LateFee != null) //Checks the Database value for latefee
            {
                //Set the late fee
                string stringfee3 = LateFee.Replace("$", "");

                //Convert late fee to integer
                intfee3 = System.Convert.ToInt32(stringfee3);
            }
     }
```

This block checks the database value of LateFee (returned earlier), sets it to a string removing the dollar sign, and then converts it to an integer.

My problem is that my .ascx file throws the error:

> "The name 'intfee3' does not exist in the current context"

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to correct it?

I am working with an asp.net website, operating against the .NET 4.0 framework, using Visual Studio 2013 as my IDE.

Thank you much!